# getMinutes() takes several refresh attempts to work properly

Tags: javascript

I noticed that the below JS code will take several refreshes (ctrl+f5) to take effect. When I manually change the time to less than 10 minutes, I have to refresh 5 or 6 times for it to work. The JS code is inside the same page (page header). Any idea how can I make it work from the first refresh after the time qualifies ?

```
function alert10ans() {

var today = new Date().getMinutes();
if (today < 10) {

      document.getElementById("myans10").removeAttribute("href");
    }

}
```

Comment: It depends completely on minutes of time which you are refreshing. This only triggered if minutes in less than 10, so this works from hour to hour. What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: To check if it's working simply console log today before if statement and check your console on load

Comment: That sounds like a cache problem. When you say *" I manually change the time"* I assume you mean edit the page/file source code and reupload it... If so then your browser is no doubt using an old copy of the source code (cache) and the multiple reload/refreshing is clearing the cache. You can either disable cache on your browser or if you run your domain through CF/CloudFlare you can enable developer mode.

Comment: If you run [this](https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/vn2spqyb/) and then adjust the time on your system do you see it update immediately?

Comment: It updates after some refreshes.